# Design a should_throttle function that limits requests based within a certain time window

Tags: python, algorithm

I was asked this algorithm question in an in-person interview at one of the big tech giants. I was not able to solve it well and it has been bothering me ever since. Here is the question and my attempt to solve it.

```
Question:
Design a should_throttle function that takes in a stream of requests.
Each request has the following format: {'client_id', 'msg_id', 'timestamp'}.
@return true if client has exceeded 1000 requests in one minute
@return false if client has NOT exceeded 1000 requests in one minute.
```

My attempted solution:

```py
def should_throttle(msg, seconds_limit=60, count_limit=1000):
    timestamp = msg['timestamp']
    client_id = msg['client_id']
    # msg_id = msg['id']

    global_dict = {} # key is timestamp, value is list of clients

    # we care only about last 60 seconds
    # so get all the keys that are within last 60 seconds OF THE CURRENT SEEN KEY
    left_range = timestamp - datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds_limit)
    right_range = timestamp

    keys_to_delete = []
    client_count = 0
    for key in global_dict.keys(): # O(60)
        if key < left_range:
            keys_to_delete.append(key)
            continue
        if key >= left_range and key <= right_range:
            if client_id in global_dict[key]: # O(1)
                client_count += global_dict[key].count(client_id)
                continue

    # delete unnecessary keys to avoid being bloated
    for key in keys_to_delete: # O(1000)
        del global_dict[key]

    # add the current msg as seen
    if timestamp in global_dict:
        global_dict[timestamp].append(client_id) # we care only about client id and wethere its seen or not
    else:
        global_dict[timestamp] = [client_id]

    if client_count >= count_limit:
        return True # throttle it

    return False
```

I keep track of the frequency of each request within a time window and clean up the entries in the dict that are outside the window.

I think the BigOh Analysis is:

```
n = max seconds window
m = max client limit

==> O(n * m)
```

Any suggestions/improvements? I really feel like I am missing a better approach to this.

Comment: I wonder if this might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: oh, I did not know about that page, will keep it in mind next time. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) by client, storing them in a defaultdict.

Then, for each incoming message, `popleft` from the deque all timestamps that are too old, add the new one, and check if the limit has been exceeded.

```
from collections import defaultdict,deque


def should_throttle(messages, seconds_limit=60, count_limit=1000):  
    recent = defaultdict(deque)

    for message in messages:
        timestamp = message['timestamp']
        client = message['client_id']
        # remove the timestamps that are more than seconds_limit old
        try:
            while recent[client][0] < timestamp - seconds_limit:
                recent[client].popleft()
        except IndexError:
            # deque was empty
            pass

        # append the current one
        recent[client].append(timestamp)

        # just to show the current state of affairs...
        print(client, recent[client])

        # has this client exceeded his limit?
        if len(recent[client]) > count_limit:
            return True

    # we never exceeded the count limit
    return False
```

Some tests:

```
should_throttle([{'client_id': 1, 'msg_id':'', 'timestamp':1},
                {'client_id': 2, 'msg_id':'', 'timestamp':20},
                {'client_id': 1, 'msg_id':'', 'timestamp':21},
                {'client_id': 1, 'msg_id':'', 'timestamp':22},
                {'client_id': 2, 'msg_id':'', 'timestamp':23},
                {'client_id': 1, 'msg_id':'', 'timestamp':24},
               ],
               seconds_limit=4, count_limit=2)
```

Output:

```
1 deque([1])
2 deque([20])
1 deque([21])
1 deque([21, 22])
2 deque([20, 23])
1 deque([21, 22, 24])

True
```

With a higher limit:

```
should_throttle([{'client_id': 1, 'msg_id':'', 'timestamp':1},
                {'client_id': 2, 'msg_id':'', 'timestamp':20},
                {'client_id': 1, 'msg_id':'', 'timestamp':21},
                {'client_id': 1, 'msg_id':'', 'timestamp':22},
                {'client_id': 2, 'msg_id':'', 'timestamp':23},
                {'client_id': 1, 'msg_id':'', 'timestamp':24},
               ],
               seconds_limit=4, count_limit=4)
```

Output:

```
1 deque([1])
2 deque([20])
1 deque([21])
1 deque([21, 22])
2 deque([20, 23])
1 deque([21, 22, 24])

False
```